# Using Htaccess to change to lower case

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, lowercase

I am transferring (301) links from one site to another.  The problem I have is that some of the links have various upper and lower case for example

```
prodview.asp?idproduct=1133
prodView.asp?idProduct=1141
prodView.asp?idproduct=1153
```

What I want to do is use Htaccess to change them all to prodview.asp?idproduct=

However the problem is that I have other incoming urls with ?idProduct and I don't want to change those just the ones after the prodview.asp?

Any help with this would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like that mod_rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule prod[vV]iew.asp?id[pP]roduct=(\d) prodview.asp?idproduct=$1`